# Inserting random characters at the end of a sentence

Tags: javascript

I want a function that will add a random symbol at the end of each sentence and remove all vowels. I know sentences could end with a ! or ? but lets just say these sentences will only end with a period. Each symbol has to be different I already inserted a asterisk to the end of the last sentence. How do I add a different symbol to the end of each sentence? This is what I have so far

```
function txtMod(str){
    var vowels = /[aioue]/gi ;
    var words = str.split(" ");
    words.splice(words.length,2,"*");
    var join = words.join(" ");
    var toStr = join.toString();
    return toStr.replace(vowels'');
}
txtMod("Hello world. This is just a test.");
```

Comment: What random symbols do you wish to add?

Comment: Any will do nothing fancy just similar to the asterisk basically shifted numeric keys. !@#$%^& and so on

Comment: The `join` method returns a string so calling `toString` on its result is a waste of CPU cycles.

Comment: Ok, I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, try this out

---

```
function getRandomSymbol() {
    var symbols = [
        '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*'
    ];
    return symbols[ Math.floor( Math.random() * symbols.length ) ];
}

function txtMod(str) {
    var vowels = /[aioue]/gi;

    return str.replace(vowels, '').split(/\./).map(function (thisSentence) {
        return thisSentence + '.' + getRandomSymbol();
    }).join('').slice(0, -2);
}

txtMod("Hello world. This is just a test. Don't mind me.");
```

---

I chained quite a few methods together there, so if you need any clarification, we can do a chat or something. Cheers.

Comment: Huh? Comes out what? Are you getting any errors in the error console?

Comment: This is what logs to the console @Joe Simmons:
'Hll wrld.# Ths s jst  tst.& Dn\'t mnd m.*.'
Just an extra period and Dn\'t

Comment: I edited my answer to fix the extra period. But what's this about an extra `Dn\'t`? That's part of the third sentence.

Comment: Do you not see it when you run it? It just has a \ after n in my editor

Comment: Nope, I do not see a backslash (or any slash). I tried it in the Scratchpad, my custom JS tester, a jsFiddle, and in a user-script (Greasemonkey). It's probably just your editor or something being fishy. Test it here in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xWKVx/

Answer (score 0):

A simple random character generator is to use `Math.random` to generate a random number and then use that number to index into a string or array. Example

```
function randomChar () {
    var template="!@#$%^&*";
    return template.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*template.length))
}
```

Then just add that char to the end of your string:

```
return txtMod(some_string) + randomChar() + randomChar();
```